# stopPropagation() but keep other click events active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code to close my menu:

```
$('body').click(function(){
  $('#menu').hide();
});
$("#menu").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;       
});
```

However on my #menu element I have some elements that have click events attached to them:

```
$('.menu_elem').live("click", function(){
  //Do something
});
```

My problem is that the e.stopPropagation() is preventing my click events for my menu. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your HTML exactly, but if `#menu` is the root of your menu and `.menu_elem` are menu items in the menu, then you could change your delegated event handling to to be captures at `#menu` like this:

```
$("#menu").on("click", ".menu_elem", function () {
   // do something
});
```

This has the following advantages:

1. It changes the delegated event handling to capture the bubbled events at `#menu` so it doesn't need propagation beyond `#menu` in order to work so you don't have to change your`.stopPropagation()` code.
2. It switches away from (the now deprecated) `.live()` to the replacement `.on()` which gives you more control over where the bubbled events are captured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.target to include or exclude the element in condition for stopPropagation,

```
$("#menu").click(function(e) {
   if(e.target.id == "menu")
   {
     e.stopPropagation();
     return false;       
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but it wasn't exactly what I needed. My fault for not being clearer in the question =(

Answer (score 0):

Write up your code that you want to execute and call it before you call stopPropagation..

```
$("#menu").click(function(e) {

// Your code here
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;       
});
```

Or use the target attribute to contain your click event